# How to make List component to fill ScrollContainer component?

Tags: html, css, sapui5, sap-fiori

I want my List component to fill ScrollContainer component. But List component sets its size automatically according to its content. Here is a screenshot of my fragment:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
    <l:Grid defaultSpan="L3 M3 S3">
        <l:content>
            <Button icon="sap-icon://filter" text="Filtrele" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L1 M1 S1" />
                </layoutData>
            </Button>
            <Button icon="sap-icon://download" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L11 M11 S11" />
                </layoutData>
            </Button>
            <ScrollContainer height="400px" vertical="true">
                <List headerText="Mevcut işler" mode="SingleSelectMaster">
                    <items>
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                        <StandardListItem title="İş takip portali projesi"
                            description="HSY" info="Geliştirme Aşamasında" infoState="Success" />
                    </items>
                </List>
            </ScrollContainer>
            <l:Grid defaultSpan="L3 M3 S3" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
                <l:content>
                    <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Çalışmanın Adı:"></Label>
                    <Label text="İş Takip Portali" class="varTxt">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L9 M9 S9" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Label>
                    <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Ekip:"></Label>
                    <Label text="HSY" class="varTxt">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L9 M9 S9" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Label>
                    <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Çalışan Kişiler:"></Label>
                    <Label text="Sercan Demirtağ, Efecan Yılmaz" class="varTxt">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L9 M9 S9" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Label>
                    <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Planlanan Başlangıç Tarihi:"></Label>
                    <Label text="28.05.2015" class="varTxt">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Label>
                    <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Planlanan Bitiş Tarihi:">
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="02.06.2015" class="varTxt">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L4 M4 S4" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Label>
                    <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Başlangıç Tarihi:"></Label>
                    <Label text="28.05.2015" class="varTxt">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Label>
                    <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Bitiş Tarihi:">
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="02.06.2015" class="varTxt">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L4 M4 S4" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Label>
                    <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Efor İç Kaynak (Adam/Gün):"></Label>
                    <Label text="28.05.2015" class="varTxt">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Label>
                    <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Efor Dış Kaynak (Adam/Gün):">
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="02.06.2015" class="varTxt">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L4 M4 S4" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Label>
                    <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Platform:"></Label>
                    <Label text="SAP" class="varTxt">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Label>
                    <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Durum:">
                    </Label>
                    <Label text="Geliştirme Aşamasında" class="varTxt">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="L4 M4 S4" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </Label>
                </l:content>
                <l:layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="L8 M8 S8" />
                </l:layoutData>
                <Label width="100%" textAlign="Right" text="Notlar:"></Label>
                <Label text="Harika gidiyor." class="varTxt">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L9 M9 S9" />
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
            </l:Grid>
        </l:content>
    </l:Grid>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I can accept any alternative solutions without the scrollcontainer. I used scrollcontainer, beacuse I couldn't fix height of the list. I'm trying to create a master/detail view. I'm not sure I'm following the best approach.

Rendered HTML:

```
<span class="sapMITBFilterCritical sapMITBFilterIcon sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="idmain1--projTab-icon" style='font-family: "SAP-icons";' data-sap-ui="idmain1--projTab-icon" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div><div class="sapMITBHorizontalWrapper"><span class="sapMITBCount">&nbsp;</span><div class="sapMITBText" id="idmain1--projTab-text">Projeler Listesi</div></div><div class="sapMITBContentArrow"></div></div></div><span class="sapMITBArrowScroll sapMITBArrowScrollRight sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__bar0--header-arrowScrollRight" style='font-family: "SAP-icons";' data-sap-ui="__bar0--header-arrowScrollRight" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div><div class="sapMITBContainerContent" id="__bar0-containerContent"><div class="sapMITBContent" id="__bar0-content"><div class="sapUiRespGrid sapUiRespGridHSpace1 sapUiRespGridMedia-Std-Desktop sapUiRespGridVSpace1" id="__grid1" data-sap-ui="__grid1"><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL1 sapUiRespGridSpanM1 sapUiRespGridSpanS1"><button class="sapMBtn sapUiSmallMarginTop" id="__button2" role="button" aria-disabled="false" type="button" data-sap-ui="__button2"><div class="sapMBtnDefault sapMBtnHoverable sapMBtnInner sapMBtnPaddingRight sapMFocusable" id="__button2-inner"><span class="sapMBtnCustomIcon sapMBtnIcon sapMBtnIconLeft sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__button2-img" style='font-family: "SAP-icons";' data-sap-ui="__button2-img" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span><span class="sapMBtnContent sapMBtnContentRight" id="__button2-content">Filtrele</span></div></button></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL2 sapUiRespGridSpanM2 sapUiRespGridSpanS2"><button class="sapMBtn sapUiSmallMarginTop" id="__button3" role="button" aria-disabled="false" type="button" data-sap-ui="__button3"><div class="sapMBtnDefault sapMBtnHoverable sapMBtnInner sapMFocusable" id="__button3-inner"><span class="sapMBtnCustomIcon sapMBtnIcon sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__button3-img" style='font-family: "SAP-icons";' data-sap-ui="__button3-img" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></button></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL1 sapUiRespGridSpanM1 sapUiRespGridSpanS1"><button class="sapMBtn sapMBtnInverted sapUiSmallMarginTop" id="__button4" role="button" aria-disabled="false" type="button" data-sap-ui="__button4"><div class="sapMBtnAccept sapMBtnHoverable sapMBtnInner sapMBtnPaddingRight sapMFocusable" id="__button4-inner"><span class="sapMBtnCustomIcon sapMBtnIcon sapMBtnIconLeft sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__button4-img" style='font-family: "SAP-icons";' data-sap-ui="__button4-img" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span><span class="sapMBtnContent sapMBtnContentRight" id="__button4-content">Değiştir</span></div></button></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL8 sapUiRespGridSpanM8 sapUiRespGridSpanS8"><button class="sapMBtn sapMBtnInverted sapUiSmallMarginTop" id="__button5" role="button" aria-disabled="false" type="button" data-sap-ui="__button5"><div class="sapMBtnHoverable sapMBtnInner sapMBtnPaddingRight sapMBtnReject sapMFocusable" id="__button5-inner"><span class="sapMBtnCustomIcon sapMBtnIcon sapMBtnIconLeft sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__button5-img" style='font-family: "SAP-icons";' data-sap-ui="__button5-img" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span><span class="sapMBtnContent sapMBtnContentRight" id="__button5-content">Sil</span></div></button></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><div class="sapMScrollCont sapMScrollContVH" id="__container3" style="width: auto; height: 400px; -ms-overflow-x: auto; -ms-overflow-y: auto;" data-sap-ui="__container3"><div class="sapMScrollContScroll" id="__container3-scroll"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMList sapMListBGSolid" id="__list15" style="width: 100%;" data-sap-ui="__list15" data-sap-ui-fastnavgroup="true"><div class="sapMListHdr">Mevcut işler</div><ul tabindex="0" class="sapMListModeSingleSelectMaster sapMListShowSeparatorsAll sapMListUl" id="__list15-listUl"><li tabindex="0" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item1" data-sap-ui="__item1"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item1-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item1-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item1-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item1-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item1-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item1-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li><li tabindex="-1" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item2" data-sap-ui="__item2"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item2-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item2-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item2-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item2-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item2-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item2-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li><li tabindex="-1" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item3" data-sap-ui="__item3"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item3-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item3-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item3-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item3-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item3-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item3-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li><li tabindex="-1" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item4" data-sap-ui="__item4"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item4-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item4-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item4-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item4-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item4-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item4-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li><li tabindex="-1" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item5" data-sap-ui="__item5"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item5-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item5-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item5-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item5-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item5-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item5-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li><li tabindex="-1" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item6" data-sap-ui="__item6"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item6-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item6-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item6-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item6-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item6-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item6-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li><li tabindex="-1" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item7" data-sap-ui="__item7"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item7-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item7-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item7-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item7-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item7-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item7-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li><li tabindex="-1" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item8" data-sap-ui="__item8"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item8-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item8-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item8-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item8-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item8-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item8-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li><li tabindex="-1" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item9" data-sap-ui="__item9"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item9-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item9-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item9-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item9-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item9-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item9-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li><li tabindex="-1" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item10" data-sap-ui="__item10"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item10-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item10-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item10-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item10-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item10-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item10-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li><li tabindex="-1" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item11" data-sap-ui="__item11"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item11-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item11-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item11-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item11-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item11-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item11-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li><li tabindex="-1" class="sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBCursor sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeInactive sapMSLI sapMSLIDescNoIcon" id="__item12" data-sap-ui="__item12"><div class="sapMLIBSelectSM" id="__item12-mode"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMPointer sapMRb" id="__item12-selectSingleMaster" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" data-sap-ui="__item12-selectSingleMaster"><div class="sapMRbB"><div class="sapMRbBOut sapMRbHoverable" id="__item12-selectSingleMaster-Button"><div class="sapMRbBInn"><input name="__list15_selectMasterGroup" tabindex="-1" id="__item12-selectSingleMaster-RB" type="radio"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapMLIBContent sapMLIBContentMargin"><div class="sapMSLIDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitleDiv"><div class="sapMSLITitle">İş takip portali projesi</div></div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv"><div class="sapMSLIDescription">HSY</div><div class="sapMSLIInfo sapMSLIInfoSuccess" id="__item12-info">Geliştirme Aşamasında</div></div></div></div></li></ul><div tabindex="0" id="__list15-after"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL8 sapUiRespGridSpanM8 sapUiRespGridSpanS8"><div class="sapUiRespGrid sapUiRespGridHSpace1 sapUiRespGridMedia-Std-Desktop sapUiRespGridVSpace1 sapUiSmallMarginTop" id="__grid0" data-sap-ui="__grid0"><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label29" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label29">Çalışmanın Adı:</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label30" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label30">İş Takip Portali</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label31" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label31">Ekip:</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label32" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label32">HSY</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label33" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label33">Çalışan Kişiler:</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label34" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label34">Sercan Demirtağ, Efecan Yılmaz</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label35" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label35">Planlanan Başlangıç Tarihi:</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label36" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label36">28.05.2015</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label37" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label37">Planlanan Bitiş Tarihi:</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label38" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label38">02.06.2015</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label39" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label39">Başlangıç Tarihi:</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label40" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label40">28.05.2015</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label41" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label41">Bitiş Tarihi:</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label42" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label42">02.06.2015</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label43" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label43">İç Kaynak (Adam/Gün):</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label44" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label44">28.05.2015</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label45" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label45">Dış Kaynak (Adam/Gün):</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label46" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label46">02.06.2015</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label47" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label47">Platform:</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label48" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label48">SAP</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label49" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label49">Durum:</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label50" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label50">Geliştirme Aşamasında</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL3 sapUiRespGridSpanM3 sapUiRespGridSpanS3"><label class="sapMLabel sapUiSelectable" id="__label51" style="width: 100%; text-align: right; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label51">Notlar:</label></div><div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL9 sapUiRespGridSpanM9 sapUiRespGridSpanS9"><label class="sapMLabel sapMLabelMaxWidth sapUiSelectable varTxt" id="__label52" style="text-align: left; direction: inherit;" data-sap-ui="__label52">Harika gidiyor.</label></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></section></div>
```

Comment: Can you also post the rendered HTML?

Comment: I added the screenshot.

Comment: It doesn't show the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use standard list items, you can use [custom list item](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.CustomListItem.html)s.

You are free to set the content of custom list items, and give the content a CSS width (in pixels or percentage), position and size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<List headerText="Mevcut işler" mode="SingleSelectMaster" width="100%">
```

Set width of list to be 100%